# Why some data is not stored in Session using memcached?

Tags: php, session, laravel, memcached

I'm trying to write some data to session using Laravel5 and Memcached. Without ajax it works fine, but i need to store multiple values asynchronously.

here is my example javascript code:

```
var i = 1;

for (i; i < 11; i++) {
    var data = {
        id: i,
        data: 'data-' + i
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/data',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data
    });
}
```

here is my example php code:

```
post('/api/data', function() {
    $request = \Request::all();

    \Session::put('key-'.$request['id'], $request['data']);
});
```

When i fire this js code once, i'm not getting all 10 values wrote to session

here is `dd(\Session::all())` after js code done output:

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "WUv8naiJT9PEHpG4b4moZyUcTfxy4YHhdBiluB7R"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "key-2" => "data-2"
  "key-5" => "data-5"
  "key-6" => "data-6"
  "key-7" => "data-7"
  "key-9" => "data-9"
]
```

If i fire js code multiple times, i get all 10 values stored.

Comment: your JS is hideously inefficient. you're doing an http call for every value you're trying to push. Most likely you're hitting a race condition: not all of those multiple ajax (which is really just http) calls have finished by the time you check what's in the session. which would explain why when you check later they "magically" appear - they hadn't reached the server yet (or been processed) when you went to see if they'd arrived yet.

Comment: I have logged requested data right now. I got all 10 values in log, which means all of requests reached the server, or i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax call are asynchrone.

so some requests are done almost at the same time. That why you have random update data in the session

Depending on which request has session_write last and read...

Here is a timeline with only 2 requests :

request 1 read session
request 2 read session
request 1 write session
request 2 write session

in the session data you have only : key-2 => data-2